# Single word for "is nothing until it becomes"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrasing

Example: Data is nothing until it becomes information, with context.

The above sentence is a bit wordy so I was hoping to find a single word to replace that phrase. I could shorten it to: Data becomes information, with context. But then it loses some meaning.

Comment: If you think a sentence is too wordy, one solution is to break it into two (each of which will have fewer words): *Without context, data is nothing. With context, it becomes information.*

Comment: I think the problem is not that the sentence is too wordy, It's that the sentence doesn't emphasize the word *context* enough. If you could find that (possibly non-existent) single word you're looking for, it would fix it. But there are lots of other ways to fix it, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn your sentence around to emphasize the role of context:

> Context turns data into information.

Here's a variant:

> Context turns raw data into information.

Or to stay closer to your original structure:

> Data alone means nothing. With context, it becomes information.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the use of *context* (if not actually emphasize it), I would reverse the sentence and say:

> Without context, data is only **potential** information.

Per Merriam-Webster's definition of [*potential*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/potential):

> **1** : existing in possibility : capable of development into actuality
>   // *potential* benefits

---

Although the sentence is reversed, the meaning is still that you need context in order to turn data into actual information. And saying that it's *only* potential information, means that it's nothing other than that. (In point of fact, data *is* something without context, just not what you want it to be.)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not too wordy, but it would benefit from rewording. It also seems like you want to stress the importance of "**context**". There are a variety of words you could use instead of "**is nothing**" which sounds "**unimportant**". You might consider other descriptive words like "**meaningless**", "**lies dormant**", or "**insignificant**" to mention a few.

> Data is **meaningless** without it's (proper) context, but it becomes
>   information when the context is applied.
>
> Data **lies dormant** until it becomes information once the (proper) context
>   is applied.
>
> Data is **insignificant** until it becomes information. It requires it's
>   (proper) context for meaning.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dormant